# Excel calculate average but need greater than a target number and the latest 5 records

Tags: excel, average

I would like to ask the excel formula that can calculate the below average. There are some conditions. Many thanks.

1. need to calculate the latest 5 records' average
2. the record need greater than 140

For the below case, suppose the average should be 150+150+160+150(3/5/2022)+150(1/5/2022) /5 = 152

| Records(col A) | marks(col B) |
| --- | --- |
| 1/5/2022 | 140 |
| 1/5/2022 | 130 |
| 1/5/2022 | 140 |
| 1/5/2022 | 150 |
| 1/5/2022 | 150 |
| 2/5/2022 | 0 |
| 2/5/2022 | 0 |
| 2/5/2022 | 0 |
| 2/5/2022 | 0 |
| 2/5/2022 | 0 |
| 3/5/2022 | 135 |
| 3/5/2022 | 150 |
| 3/5/2022 | 160 |
| 3/5/2022 | 150 |
| 3/5/2022 | 150 |

Comment: Have you tried averageifs(), criteria of >140 and highest date?

Comment: I tried below formula but not work: AVERAGEIF(OFFSET($A$3,COUNT($A$3:$A$5000)-1,0,0-COUNTIF(OFFSET($A$3,COUNT($A$3:$A$5000)-1,0,-5,1),"<140")-5,1),">=140")

Comment: Averageifs)) not averageif()…

Comment: See my answer, why are you doing a lon g countif() looking for <140?

Comment: because I would like to calculate the latest 5 records' average that the marks need greater than 139, I watched your answer, the average is 152.5 ((150+150+160+150)/4), but I would like to calculate latest  5 records' average that the marks >= 140. Therefore 1/5/2022 150 marks(B6) should be included. The result will be (150+150+160+150+150)/5 = 152  ,that means (B16+B15+B14+B13+B6)/5

Comment: Sorry I wrote a wrong condition ,the record need greater than 139, not 140

Comment: So changing 140 to 139 in cell D4  or E9, depending which solution you look at is not difficult. As for expanding the date range then it will be good experience for you to work on that, I have given two slightly different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:
[image]

Use averageifs():

[image]

Cell D4 has the lower limit and E6 the latest date using max().

Cell D8 is just the average of the last 4 to check.